# Can't see texture through Principled Node?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, 3d-view

Maybe I am missing something obvious but when I connect my image texture to principled shader (using PBR Material Nodes) it doesn't show the texture in rendered viewport, or in materials viewport.

[image]

But through typical Diffuse Node, everything works fine. Using cycles.

[image]
Halp?

Comment: How many UV channels are there in your object?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos only 1 UV Map

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the reason. My Subsurface scattering was maxed to 1, but if you want to see the texture, it needs to be lowered.